# mongodb nodejs how to set field as current time in the db?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a NodeJS application that uses the latest version of the MongoDB driver.
I use updateMany with $set to update a field to the current timestamp, however I want it to be the current timestamp in the DB and not in the NodeJS server.
Basically the "$$NOW" operation, if it was supported in updateMany in Node MongoDB

I tried using new Date() but as I said I want the time in the DB server and not the nodeJS server
I tried using $$NOW but it is not supported in updateMany in nodejs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try update with pipeline:

```
db.collection.updateMany(
  {},
  [{$set: {now: "$$NOW"}}]
)
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5EaLrrXPhsa) (which does not support `updateMany`)

Comment: Adding the square brackets worked, thanks!